Home settling, how necessary is repair needed?
For my Missouri 50 year old house, I had a few estimates out and have been told that the front corner of my house is settling about an inch. The front wall is bowed 1.2” and side wall 1”. There are some vertical and diagonal cracks in the area. The expensive estimates (35-50k) want to install piers along both walls and brace the front wall and then patch the cracks. The cheap estimate (22k)wants to brace both walls and then install a waterproofing drain tile/sump pump system (would not patch cracks because of this). I guess I’m wondering, the cheap fix seems like a bandaid without piering but we plan to live here 5-7 years, is the settling severe enough to need to do more? Am I likely okay just bracing and handing the finished work and it’s (likely crappy) warranty to the next owners? I’ve attached pictures here https://imgur.com/a/foundation-pics-1bBZtP4
